# Any rational as integer plus sum of $n$ reciprocals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does there exist an integer $n$ with the following property?

For any rational number $r$, there exist integers $a,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ such that $r=a+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{b_i}$.

Comment: See [Egyptian fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we choose $u$ maximal subject to ${s\over t}-{1\over u}\ge0$ then $su-t<s$, and argue by induction (or well-ordering).

Comment: Note that this gives a way to write any rational $r$ as a finite sum of unit fractions, for each $r$. However, this says nothing about whether you can do it for all $r$ using exactly $n$ terms, where $n$ is fixed and is not allowed to depend on $r$.

Comment: @Ivan, you can't fix $n$ independent of $r$. See, for example, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33628/whats-the-simplest-rational-not-expressible-as-a-sum-of-a-given-number-of-unit

Comment: I am aware of the fact that there are rationals with arbitrarily long Egyptian fraction representation, but I haven't read the proof before, so I'm not sure if the proof may be adapted to answer OP's question, where we may vary $a$ (so even if $r$ is not expressible in $n$ terms, it is still conceivable that we may somehow choose $a$ s.t. $r-a$ is expressible in $n$ terms)

Comment: @Ivan, I see your point. But I think you would have to choose $a$ such that $r+a$ is expressible in fewer terms than $r$, as (I believe) there are rationals $r$ between 0 and 1 with arbitrarily long representations.